# Access token issues in FOSOAuth Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, oauth-2.0

Two things:

1. I'm currently using one login form for regular user login and for redirect to `authorize` endpoint ( first step of authentication ). When I'm accessing authorize endpoint I have to pass `client id` and `response type` - how to do it? Only solution I can think of is to manualy render login form and redirect to `authorize` endpoint with parameters I want, but than I won't be able to use one login form as I'm doing it now. It's shown only how to redirect after creating a new client:

   ```
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_oauth_server_authorize',
     array(
        'client_id'     => $client->getPublicId(),
        'redirect_uri'  => 'http://www.example.com',
        'response_type' => 'code'
    )));
   ```

   but it's not matching situation after user logs in.
2. Situation when user is logged in and have valid access token - I want to pass it to him ( for example add it to _GET ) but have no idea how. I was trying with `EventListener` but my firewall

   > ```
   >  api:
   >             pattern:    ^/api
   >             fos_oauth:  true
   >             stateless:  true
   > ```

   rejects it before `EventListener` starts.

Comment: Why don't you use HwiOAuthBundle [https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle] for this one.

Comment: Because I think that it doesn't require whole bundle to do that. Currently I just want to issue already existing token to user, before FOS cheks whether the user has token.